# How to change default integreated terminal in VS Code to kitty, on Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm using kitty (it's a terminal) on Linux, and I want it to be used in VS Code as default terminal (which appears when I click Ctrl+`). Right now VS Code uses its own terminal with name "vscode".

I tried modifying settings by adding there
`"terminal.external.linuxExec": "/usr/bin/kitty"`
but it didn't help.

When I click `Select Default Profile` it only allows me to choose between `zsh` and `bash`.

How do I change default terminal to kitty?

UPDATE:
I've added kitty profile like so

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "bash": {
      "path": "bash",
      "icon": "terminal-bash"
    },
    "zsh": {
      "path": "zsh"
    },
    ... other profiles

    "kitty": {
      "path": "/usr/bin/kitty"
    }
  },
```

But when I choose `kitty` now, it opens the terminal outside of VS Code.

Comment: have you create a terminal profile for kitty

Comment: nope, how did I do it? @rioV8

Comment: ok, I added a profile. In "path" I set "/usr/bin/kitty", but when I choose this profile it simply opens kitty terminal outside of vscode @rioV8

Comment: edit the question and show how you defined the profile, the json part from settings.json

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that's a thing, u have a shell in linux in which u execute commands the terminal, to my knowledge is simply a sort of runner to work the shell, so i know that u can either switch to zsh or bash, like zshell or bash or fish or dash

U can just switch your default shell as well, so that u can just use your aliases in the codeoss terminal,
first do 'echo $SHELL'
then u'll get your current shell, (/usr/bin/zsh, /bin/zsh, /bin/bash, /bin/dash)
then just do 'cat /etc/shells' you'll get a list of all installed shells and u can just choose whichever u want to switch to, then just do 'chsh' it'll ask which shell nd just enter /bin/ and u'll be done, that should also change the shell in VScode
and now all your aliases should be useable, in case of compatibility errors with script generally zsh scripts and bash scripts work with each other, i dont hv experience with others.
thank u

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).